# Freeing resources in D language

Tags: d, direct3d, direct3d11

When using Direct3D in c++ I can write a "Cube" class for example, that contains a "ID3D11Buffer* vertexBuffer_" and ensure that the destructor for that Cube object calls vertexBuffer_->Release().

I can have a "Scene" class containing a "unique_ptr cube_" object. So that I know that when I delete my scene, the cube will be deleted, and that will consequently call release on the D3D resources it is using.

In D I can't do this. I can write destructors but I have no idea when they will be called. If the GC doesn't require the memory they may never be called...

So what is the best way to handle this kind of thing in D? I could add a "Free" member function to each of the objects that frees all of it's own resources and calls "Free" on any objects it owns, but this seems an error prone manual operation and a step backwards from C++.

Is there a better way to handle this kind of thing in D?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a struct on the stack. *That* has deterministic destruction. You can even have it be refcounted by using [std.typecons.RefCounted](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#RefCounted). Don't use a struct on the heap though if you want to guarantee that the destructor runs. At the moment, I don't think that structs' destructors ever get run if they're put on the heap, because the GC doesn't have the information that it needs to do so (that should be fixed at some point in the future though).

But if you insist on putting it in on the heap in a class, and you want to explicitly destroy the object, then you can call `clear` on it:

```
clear(obj);
```

That will call the object's destructor and then put it in an invalid state, and anything that tries to use it after that should blow up (IIRC, the virtual table gets zeroed out). But the memory isn't actually freed. That's the GC's job. And don't use `delete`. It's going to be deprecated. I'm actually surprised that it hasn't been yet, since it's been planned for ages to get rid of it.

And of course, one option is to have an explicit function that you call to release the resources. Whether that's a good idea or not depends on what you're doing. But regardless, classes are intended to be collected by the GC and not be freed whenever you choose to.

Work is being done on custom allocators, which would give you more options for how to allocate a class, and one of those would probably allow you to have more deterministic destruction of classes, but that's not ready yet.

And if you're feeling crazy, you can use [std.typecons.scoped](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#scoped), which replaces the soon to be deprecated type modifier `scope` (though `scope` is sticking around in other contexts - such as `scope` statements). It puts a class on the stack. But that's unsafe (which is why `scope` is going away in this context), and you probably might as well just use a struct if you're going to stick the object on the stack.

**EDIT:** You could also use `malloc` and `free` with [std.conv.emplace](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_conv.html#emplace) to put the object in a non-GC allocated chunk of memory like you'd have in C++, but I think that you'd have to explicitly call the destructor to get it run, since `free` doesn't understand about destructors (it being a C function). That would have the advantage of making the memory go away along with the resource (whereas using `clear` on an object on the GC heap would just destroy the object's contents, not free the memory), but I don't know that that buys you much over using `clear` on a GC-allocated object.

However, you could then create a free function similar to `new` which does the `malloc` and `emplace` for you, and then have a free function similar to `delete` which calls the destructor and `free`, which would give you the same situation as C++. In fact, I wonder if that would be useful enough to make it into the standard library. That's probably the sort of thing that'll end up in the custom allocators though. So, it wouldn't surprise me at all if in the relatively near future, you could use a custom allocator to do something like

```
auto obj = customAllocObj.create!MyObj(args);
//Do stuff...
customAllocObj.destroy(obj);
```

And I would think that that would solve your problem fairly well given that that's essentially the same thing that you'd have in C++, just with library functions rather than with the built-in `new` and `delete`. I think that I'll bring it up on the newsgroup. I expect that there are at least some folks who would like such a feature, and that does seem to fit in nicely with custom allocators.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer!
I'm not sure I can use a struct on the stack as my objects have a lifetime of longer than that. clear might work for me, but it doesn't seem that different from my own clear() function. Ypu've given me more things to think about anyway :)

Comment: @JohnB I was assuming that you'd probably be passing the struct around, but it's definitely true that that may not work, depending on your situation. If you do your own function though, I'd advise not called the destructor in it - that's just asking for trouble (though the destructor could call whatever your function is that frees the resources). So, if you really want to call the destructor, then use `clear`. If all you want to do is free the resource though,  then it may make more sense to call another function specifically for that rather than destroying the object. It depends on your code.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify: Destructors are *always* called. If an object has not been finalized by the time the application shuts down, the GC runs its finalizer.

I don't see how manually calling a free() function to delete the vertex buffer is any more error prone than having to manage memory manually in C++. Anyway, you may want to look at: http://www.dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#scoped and http://www.dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#RefCounted

Comment: The problem is that destructors are called when the memory is freed which will be at some point in the future when the GC notices that the object isn't referred to any more. I need the D3D objects to be released immediately, not at some undefined point in the future...

Comment: [`delete`](http://www.d-programming-language.org/expression.html#DeleteExpression)? "If the UnaryExpression is a class object reference, and there is a destructor for that class, the destructor is called for that object instance."

Comment: `delete` is being removed from the language. Don't use it. You can use `clear`, which will call the object's destructor and invalidate the object, but it won't free the memory. That's the GC's job. If you want deterministic destruction, then use a struct.

Comment: If the class I "clear()" has other class objects as data members, I presume they are not cleared, and I'd have to manually code that in the destructor? Which is basically what I'm trying to avoid having to do. None of this is a problem, I just feel that I've either found something that works better in c++ than d which is disapointing, or I'm missing some idiom in d for achieving what I want to do.

Comment: @JohnB Right. That was just a clarification. Your only options are manually calling some free() function or using ref counting / scoped.

Comment: @JohnB You could make some gcFree(void*) function which calls clear() on the object and then GC.free()s it. That would give you the same "features" as C++ does.